# How is PostgreSQL's extension system implemented?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, c

I am interested in how PostgreSQL's extension system is implemented. How can a postgres server call user-defined C which is built separately from the server.

---

This question comes from [Reddit u/lllouiskuang on /r/postgresql](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/14dyipc/how_is_postgresqls_extension_system_implemented/)

Comment: Your question is asking two unrelated things. There are extensions, and there are C functions, and they have nothing in common (except that a C function can be a member of an extension).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the question I found was "How is PostgreSQL's extension system implemented?" I fully agree with you. That's why I tried to separate these things in my answer below: _"a PostgreSQL Extension isn't just compiled C code though, it's versioning and migration/upgrade information."_ The question was specific to C code, so I didn't entertain that an extension can exist with no C code. But I could have written that I'll expand the answer. Still I think a question about a high level overview of how extensions work is _certainly_ on topic.

Comment: Oh, I absolutely agree. But you should make that two questions: one about the extension system, and one about how C functions work. Otherwise it is confusing for the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL [dynamically loads shared objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-DYNLOAD). A shared object is basically a mapping of symbols to stuff (functions, etc) that gets copied into the memory space of a process. For more information on this, look up `libdl` which provides `dlopen` (which loads the file) and `dlsym` (which finds the symbol). This is very common in C. This `libdl` functionality is called in pg's `internal_load_library` and `load_external_function` implementations.

The API around this is called an extension. These shared objects provide functions which must be marked as following the calling convention (with `PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1()`). Then an extension is `LOAD`ed explicitly, or you call `CREATE EXTENSION`. When initialized, PostgreSQL looks for and calls a function called `_PG_init` in this shared object, and when it's unloaded PostgreSQL calls `_PG_fini`. This is where you can implement any hooks, a hook is functionality PostgreSQL calls after the extension is loaded based on events that the sever triggers. It's not functionality for the *user* to call explicitly.

A PostgreSQL Extension isn't just compiled C code though, it's versioning and migration/upgrade information. This is where you can tell PostgreSQL what is using the symbol defined in your shared object. For example, this code from an extension I made,

```
CREATE FUNCTION repeat_materialize_preferred(object int4, times int4)
RETURNS TABLE(repeat int4)
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'repeat_materialize_preferred'
LANGUAGE C STRICT VOLATILE;
```

Is run when you call `CREATE EXTENSION`. This is what tells PostgreSQL the function available in SQL named `repeat_materialize_preferred` is found in symbol `repeat_materialize_preferred`, which is a shared object that follows the C ABI and the PostgreSQL calling convention; this function takes two int4 arguments and returns a rowset of int4. If it wasn't for this call to `CREATE FUNCTION` the shared object would be loaded in memory and unavailable to the user.

As to being built separate from the server, this is possible because you need the development files for PostgreSQL -- the headers and libraries and tooling that correspond to the server -- you don't actually need the server itself. Every extension must be built for the specific version of the server it runs on though (though it may work if built for an earlier server since PostgreSQL doesn't really break backwards compatability much.)

---

Footnote from the comments: while this question was specific to C, a PostgreSQL extension is not limited to C and can be written in many other languages, including Rust, Node/v8, Python, Perl, and plpgsql.